# How do I convert a Graphic to a different coordinate system in ArcGIS?

Tags: silverlight, arcgis, map-projections

I am trying to add functionality to a Silverlight ArcGIS application that allows shapefiles to be uploaded and displayed on the map. Whenever I upload a shapefile, it displays it correctly but in the wrong place, such as a shape that should be in Texas being drawn in the Sahara.

I'm pretty sure the problem is that our map uses a different coordinate system than each shapefile, but I haven't been able to find any resources that can successfully convert the shapefile coordinates. [WebMercator.FromGeographic](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/apiref/ESRI.ArcGIS.Client~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Projection.WebMercator~FromGeographic.html) works for some of the shapefiles, but causes the application to crash for others.

I've tried using a GeometryService and have tried altering the SpatialReferences for the shapes, but neither had any noticeable effect.

The PRJ for the file that didn't work with FromGeographic looks like this:

> PROJCS["Basic Albers WGS84",GEOGCS["D_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Albers"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-96.0],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",45.5],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",29.5],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",23.0],UNIT["Foot_US",0.3048006096012192]]

Where can I start looking to figure this out?

EDIT:

Here is the code for how the Polygon Graphic is created:

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.Polygon geo = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.Polygon();

ObservableCollection<ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.PointCollection> paths = new ObservableCollection<ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.PointCollection>();

ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.PointCollection pcol = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.PointCollection();

foreach (System.Windows.Point p in this.points)
{
    MapPoint mp = new MapPoint();
    mp.X = p.X;
    mp.Y = p.Y;

    pcol.Add(mp);
}

paths.Add(pcol);

geo.Rings = paths;

// Random WKID to test with.
geo.SpatialReference = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.SpatialReference(3174);

ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Graphic gr = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Graphic()
{
    Geometry = geo,
    Symbol = window.Get(symbolPolygon) as ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Symbols.Symbol,
};

return gr;
```

The GeometryService is used like this:

```
GraphicsLayer graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();

foreach (ShapefileRecord r in sh.Records)
{
    Graphic g = r.ToGraphic(this);
    graphicsLayer.Graphics.Add(g);
}

geoServ.ProjectAsync(graphicsLayer.Graphics.ToList(), new ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.SpatialReference(102100));

Map.Layers.Add(graphicsLayer);
```

Comment: Since you tried using the GeometryService to project what version? Only v10+ supports projection strings

Comment: `.FromGeographic` is definitely not going to work for that SR. :) Have you got some code you used with the GeometryService? That would certainly seem like the way to solve the problem - are you setting the SR of the input geometries correctly...?

Comment: @dotMorten, I believe it's 10, but I'm not sure how to check to confirm.

Comment: @Juffy, I have been setting the SpatialReference of the points in the polygon and the Geometry as a whole, but it doesn't seem to be having any effect. I'll add some code to the OP.

Comment: Zack: You can check the root of the rest service where it says "Current Version". Example: http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be a complete answer, but there's too much info for a comment.

Your source SR, `3174`, is incorrect. The [WKT](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3174/html/) of that SR is significantly different from the .PRJ file you posted:

```
PROJCS["NAD83 / Great Lakes Albers",
    GEOGCS["NAD83",
        DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",
            SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    PROJECTION["Albers_Conic_Equal_Area"],
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",42.122774],
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",49.01518],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",45.568977],
    PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",-84.455955],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",1000000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",1000000],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","3174"],
    AXIS["X",EAST],
    AXIS["Y",NORTH]]
```

...where the worst problem is that your .PRJ file has `UNIT["Foot_US",0.3048006096012192]`, while 3174 has `UNIT["metre",1]`! This is probably why things are appearing in the Sahara. :)

I think your best bet is to use [this constructor](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/apiref/ESRI.ArcGIS.Client~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.SpatialReference~_ctor(String).html) of the SpatialReference class, and feed it the WKT you posted from the PRJ file.

Comment: Thank you so much! Turns out I had two problems - this was one of them, as I had no idea I could instantiate an SpatialReference just with the WKT.

It also turned out that I was using GraphicsService incorrectly. Just in case anyone else has this same problem and finds this answer, I used the example on [this page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/silverlight-api/apiref/api_start.htm?ESRI.ArcGIS.Client~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.GeometryService~ProjectAsync(IEnumerable%7BGraphic%7D,SpatialReference).html) to figure it out.